# PIL Image.open() variable input AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter, jpeg, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to display an image on Tkinter using the filepath as an Entry object. It was necessary to use PIL as it was a .jpg file. But even though I am able to retrieve the filepath from the tk.Entry as a string, I am not able to display it onto the Tkinter Canvas. Here are some important lines of the code regarding the problem.

```
path = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, width=60, textvariable=path)
e1.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path.get()))
canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\GUI.py", line 60, in <module>
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path.get()))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2549, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How do I go about solving this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: it seems that your `path.get()` is not a valid filepath. can you show what's in `path.get()` ?

Comment: You're calling `path.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget. The user won't have even seen the widget yet, much less be able to type into it.

Comment: path.get() has the entry filepath(whatever input I give, which happens to be the image file path). I could've just used e1.get() but I encountered some problems with it. so It seemed better to create a StringVar and use path.get()

Comment: so is there no way to immediately  display the image after I give the filepath? What will solve the problem? by giving a delay?
I think the problem seems to be with PIL trying to use a variable to display it on the canvas.
When it is img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("photo.jpg")) It works fine. but when I use a variable, It reads it as a string. I found some help by using StringIO, but none of it seems to work/